# react native: double tap needed for ScrollView / FlatList / SectionList?

Tags: react-native

If I have data in a `ScrollView`, `FlatList`, or `SectionList`, and that data includes a button that the user can press on, tapping on the button once hides the Keyboard as expected:

```
onScroll={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
```

but it does not trigger the button callback. It only works if you tap the same button a second time **after** the keyboard is hidden. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

I figured out the answer [from the docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#keyboardshouldpersisttaps), setting `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"`

Comment: Accept this as the answer.